# Is there a VPF (VMAP) writer?

Tags: postgis, gdal, geotools, arccatalog, opengis

Hi I'm looking for a writer that can store points in VPF format (VMAP). Is ther something out there, preferably in open source, and better yet in JAVA?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything public. VPF is a format on the trailing edge of support. Can you use something else?